# SSIS DataReader fail from Mainframe

Tags: ssis, odbc, mainframe, datareader

I have an ADO.Net connection using an ODBC data source to connect to our mainframe.  When it's connected to a DataReader Source, the Datareader immediately fails. I'm assuming at the very least the connection is working correctly because a Select * From (not that I'm using one) in the SqlCommand will correctly show all of the available columns under column mappings.  When trying to dump to a simple flat file, I get this.

```
SSIS package "MainframeTest.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Destination [191]: The processing of file "C:\Documents and Settings\BBSA322\Desktop\LogFile.txt" has started.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC02090F5 at Data Flow Task, DataReader Source [1]: The component "DataReader Source" (1) was unable to process the data.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "DataReader Source" (1) returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047021 at Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread "SourceThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0047038.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
Error: 0xC0047039 at Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADCANCELLED.  Thread "WorkThread0" received a shutdown signal and is terminating. The user requested a shutdown, or an error in another thread is causing the pipeline to shutdown.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread was cancelled.
Error: 0xC0047021 at Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread "WorkThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0047039.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0047018 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: component "DataReader Source" (1) failed the post-execute phase and returned error code 0x8007000E.
Error: 0xC0047018 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: component "DataReader Source" (1) failed the post-execute phase and returned error code 0x8007000E.
Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Destination [191]: The processing of file "C:\Documents and Settings\BBSA322\Desktop\LogFile.txt" has ended.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC004701B at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: component "DataReader Source" (1) failed the cleanup phase and returned error code 0x8007000E.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: "component "Flat File Destination" (191)" wrote 0 rows.
Error: 0xC0047037 at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: component "DataReader Source" (1) failed during shut down and returned error code 0x8007000E. A component failed to release its interfaces.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at MainframeTest: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (9) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "MainframeTest.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Comment: What is the database on the mainframe?

Comment: What are the data types in the source RDBMS and how do those map to columns in the dataflow? Did you happen to change the transaction level from the default of Supported to Required?

Comment: Everything's a DT_WSTR, same as the flat file, and the transaction level is still supported.  Honestly, at this point I'm just trying to get anything out of the mainframe, so I'm only pulling out two columns.

Comment: Figured it out.  It was a problem with a .Net framework update. You can work around it by adding a text file to the error output of the data reader. Answer was found here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/04/09/after-installation-of-net-framework-3-5-sp1-or-net-framework-2-0-sp2-ssis-packages-using-odbc-3rd-party-drivers-may-fail.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was a problem with a .Net framework update.  Adding a text file to the error output fixed the problem.

Answer found here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/04/09/after-installation-of-net-framework-3-5-sp1-or-net-framework-2-0-sp2-ssis-packages-using-odbc-3rd-party-drivers-may-fail.aspx